# Sometimes the icons are broken/weird looking when page is loaded JS / VUEJS / BOXICONS

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons

I am using the icons in my applications but sometimes when the page is loaded the icons look borken(weird):

[image]

But that is how icons should appear:

[image]

I am using the icons like this:

[image]

[image]